# Highcharts Sankey diagram direction reversal issue

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, sankey-diagram

Wanted to revese the rendering of Highcharts Sankey Diagram from `left-to-right` to `right-to-left`. according to [Highcharts forum](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=45046), it was suggested to switch the keys value from:

```
 series: [{
        keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
        data: ... 
        }]
```

to:

```
 series: [{
        keys: ['to', 'from', 'weight'],
        data: ...
        }]
```

---

### Output:

before:
[image: Before:]

After:
[image: After:]

### Code:

Left-to-right diagram (rendering Fine!): [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/Baliga/6t14qrj0)

right-to-left diagram (Not rendering properly): [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/Baliga/6t14qrj0/7/)

---

Referring the abv. image, once the `keys` are switched the diagram is not rendering properly. Ideally, wanted to render diagrams in both `left-to-right` and `right-to-left` directions.

Comment: It seems the diagram is rendering (in jsfiddle). Do you mean the result is not what you expect?

Comment: I see the same image after rendering right to left as you show in the picture only one time after first refresh (It could be a bug with a refresh, I will try to fix it), after to second refresh looks are you expected?

Comment: Sorry, I had linked the wrong URL (have updated it in the question) or you can check this fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/Baliga/6t14qrj0/7/

Comment: I recreated and changed `series.keys` in the official demo and can't see the behavior from your case, could you check this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ahLdre0m/)?

Comment: @SebastianHajdus you should be able to replicate the issue when u reduce the data, if you can remove some of the nodes, the diagram starts to fail. can you check this? https://jsfiddle.net/Baliga/6t14qrj0/7/

Comment: It looks like the miss of data caused the problem, I have tried different data and it looks good, like here [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6p9t15yr/).

Comment: @SebastianHajdus can you try the same with multi steps/levels? (currently in the demo it is single level)

Comment: You can still option to configure your Sankey chart, [example](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6p9t15yr/1/), based on this [article](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/what-is-a-sankey-diagram/) and [docs](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sankey.nodes).

Comment: @SebastianHajdus the example fails when you switch the keys, you can view it here: https://jsfiddle.net/Baliga/oLjvm6wd/

Comment: When you switch keys try turning off the offset, you need to adjust the chart so, I think you can submit this as a feature request on GH, for smooth changing direction from keys it will be a cool idea.